# Schrader O., Reallexikon der indogermanischen Altertumskunde:

Tags: dictionary, textbooks

I' m very sorry, does anyone have  Schrader O., Reallexikon der indogermanischen Altertumskunde, 1917?
Is it copyright free?

Comment: does it exist with that date? De Gruyter (the publisher) lists it with the date 1901, not 1917

Comment: @Tristan https://www.degruyter.com/serial/riga-b/html?lang=de

Comment: Is this valid for this site? Usually, questions re resources go on META.

Answer (score 3):

You can read it here: https://archive.org/details/reallexikonderi00schrgoog

It is out of copyright.

Comment: It is 1901 (not 1917)

Comment: @HungarianMan looking carefully through the De Gruyter listing, it's clear the version here includes the 1917 and 1929 volumes as well as the 1901 matter. It being listed with the publication date as 1901 appears to be a mistake

Comment: or rather it is the 1901 material listed here: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783112337721/html?lang=de